# How to add two light maps to two different objects that share same material

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two objects that share same material and have some animation and i want to add a light map for each one of them, how to do it without play with that shared material, i have tried the following

```
             childer[i].materials.lightMap=ObjectsLightMaps[childer[i].id];
```

but it's not working

Comment: 2 different lightmaps will need 2 different materials

Comment: @2pha should i clone the material  ?

Comment: Yes, you need to clone the material.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy  
I'm using Collada with three.js to apply lightmap to objects it keep giving the objects the last lightmap. anyhelp?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot both share a material and have different maps on that material; you must clone the material to make changes. Starting from your example:

```
childer[i].materials = childer[i].materials.clone();
childer[i].materials.lightMap = ObjectsLightMaps[childer[i].id];
```

[Docs for THREE.Material.clone()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material.clone), three.js r89.